# Serilog not logging anymore after upgrading to 2.*

Tags: serilog

We have a large application (about 40 projects) that uses .NET Framework 4.8 and C# in VS 2019. It includes a couple of WCF services and a bunch of Web Apps using different "old" technologies (WebForms, ASP.NET MVC).
We are trying to upgrade Serilog from 1.5.14 to 2.11.0.

The upgrade went fine following the upgrade guide (see [Upgrade Guide here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/2.x-Upgrade-Guide)), and the project compiles and runs fine.

The problem is that it doesn't log anything anymore: each separate service and web app has its own Serilog configuration (using XML AppSettings), but no log file is created and of course no logging is done, and the configuration hasn't been changed. No exception or anything like that is thrown either.

The problem might be that the configuration is not read for some reason, or there is something to add missing from the upgrade guide. The original code that initializes the logger looks like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                    .CreateLogger();
Log.Information("Service Starting");
```

If I change the code to be like this:

```
var l = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings().Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().WriteTo.File("c:\\logs\\log.txt");
Log.Logger = l.CreateLogger();
Log.Information("Service Starting");
```

Then magically the "log.txt" file is created and everything is logged into it, but using "Debug" settings, so again it looks like the config is not read.

This is my typical Serilog configuration:

```
    <appSettings>
    <!--Serilog-->
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
    <!--trace logging-->
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Trace" value="Serilog.Trace" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Trace.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Debug" />
    <!--rolling file logging-->
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile" value="Serilog.RollingFileSink" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Information" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\Service-{Date}.log" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
</appSettings>
```

And below is the list of packages installed on the project configured as above:

```
<package id="Serilog" version="2.11.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Exceptions" version="8.4.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Console" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Observable" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.TextWriter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Trace" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SerilogMetrics" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Anybody who can help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end after looking at some different pieces of docs I've found what the missing bits were.
The updated configuration above needs to look like this:

```
        <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File" value="Serilog.FileSink" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Information" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="C:\Logs\Service-.log" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Day" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
```

The config above works the same as the previous configuration and without the need to use the deprecated RollingFile sink.

The key thing here is the "using" line: without that nothing gets logged and no exception is thrown.
The second thing is the additional "rollingInterval" line that appends the date to the provided file name (note the "pathFormat" changed into just "path" there).

Hope it can be useful for somebody else.